# CPLEX minimize piecewise linar functions

Tags: java, optimization, cplex, nonlinear-optimization

I'm currently setting up a Java program using cplex. I want to find the minimum of a cost function with lots of terms.

Now it turns out that some of these cost terms should not be linear but piecewise linear. I know that CPLEX can do this - but how? I can hardly find any information or tutorials on that.

Does anyone have experience with this and can recommend/show me some tutorials or code snippets?

This would be super helpful... Thanks in advance!
Philipp

Here my code:

```
IloLinearNumExpr toMinimize = cplex.linearNumExpr();
for(float hour = start; hour <=  end; hour += stepSize){
            IloNumVar Purchase = cplex.numVar(0, Double.MAX_VALUE, "Purchase_" + hour);
            PurchasePerHour.put(hour, Purchase);
            toMinimize.addTerm(Rate, Purchase);

            IloNumVar eSale = cplex.numVar(-Double.MAX_VALUE, 0, "Sale_" + hour);
            SalePerHour.put(hour, Sale);
            toMinimize.addTerm(SaleRate/4000, eSale);   
/*
here should be a term similar to the sale/purchase ones above being piecewise linearly dependent from a variable
*/

    }

cplex.addMinimize(toMinimize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Transport cplex example.  There is a java version there that uses a piecewise linear objective function.

Comment: All right! I just found it by myself... should have been taking a better look, sorry!

This is exactly what I was looking for...
Nevertheless, thank you very much!